# strongSwan failed to start

Tags: vpn, l2tp

I am configuring L2TP VPN on Ubuntu 20.4 client.
After the following installation from [this site](https://support.strongvpn.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003656534-L2TP-Setup-Ubuntu-), when I want to restart ipsec `/usr/sbin/ipsec start` I get this error:

```
Starting strongSwan 5.8.2 IPsec [starter]...
charon is already running (/var/run/charon.pid exists) -- skipping daemon start
/etc/ipsec.conf:1: missing value for setting 'config'
invalid config file '/etc/ipsec.conf'
unable to start strongSwan -- fatal errors in config
```

What's the solution?

Here it is of my /etc/ipsec.conf:
[image]

---

**My newest update (2020-07-10**)

```
root@ubuntu:/home/username# /usr/sbin/ipsec start
Starting strongSwan 5.8.2 IPsec [starter]...
charon is already running (/var/run/charon.pid exists) -- skipping daemon start
/etc/ipsec.conf:2: missing value for setting 'conn'
invalid config file '/etc/ipsec.conf'
unable to start strongSwan -- fatal errors in config
```

[image]

Comment: Did you even read the output? 1) it clearly states the daemon is already running (probably controlled via systemd), 2) your config is apparently invalid.

Comment: `/etc/ipsec.conf:1: missing value for setting 'config'` – could you at least add that 1st line to your question?

Comment: @digijay
 I have updated my post

Comment: @ecdsa
Whats the solution?